# How to make my eBay search bar specific to my store?

Tags: javascript, html, search, ebay-design-templates

I have recently re-designed the look of my company's eBay store, and have put a custom search bar in place. However, when my user's search for a product, it is not searching for products in my store in particular. Instead, it is doing a general eBay search.

I have included my full code in a JSFiddle for you helpful people to check out, and would really appreciate it if anyone can tell me how to make it so it searches only for products in my store in particular.

Thanks in advance:
JS FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/DanCUK89/U6LqJ/

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="search" method="get"
action="http://search.stores.ebay.com/search/search.dll?GetResult&">
   <input type="text" name="query" maxlength="300" >
   <input type="hidden" name="fcd" value="2">
   <input type="hidden" name="from" value="R10">
   <input type="hidden" name="sasel" value="<Your store number>">
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Search">
   <br />
   <input type="checkbox" name="srchdesc" value="y">search titles & descriptions
</form>
```

or try this

```
<form name="search" method="get" action="http://search.stores.ebay.com/search/search.dll">
Search Our Store:
<input type="text" name="query" size="7">
<input type="submit" value="Go" width="20" height="16" border="0">
<input type="hidden" name="MfcISAPICommand" value="GetResult">
<input type="hidden" name="sid" value="ENTER STORE ID HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="store" value="ENTER STORE NAME HERE">
<input type="hidden" name="colorid" value="15">
<input type="hidden" name="fp" value="0">
<input type="hidden" name="srchdesc" value="y">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @Trinh Hoang Nhu, unfortunately I'm unable to find my sasel number, I'm having real issues finding it!

Comment: Yes, the shop ID is Pinknoise-Systems, but I have tried using sid="Pinknoise-Systems" as well as seasel="Pinknoise-Systems" will no success.

Comment: There is a id number also, can you find it?

Comment: There is a guide here http://pages.ebay.com/help/sell/stores-tags.html

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
"/your _store/_i.html
```

on form acion like this:

```
<form action="/your_store/_i.html">
```

your_store is the liunk to your store like this:

```
stores.ebay.com/your_store
```